# Javascript: Alerts not working using onclick in html

Tags: javascript, html, image, onclick

I've been writing some code for a school project, and I need some images to trigger popup alerts with information when clicked. I don't know exactly what the problem, but I'm really new to this and I most likely just got some formatting wrong somewhere.

Here you can see the function I have for making the alerts:

```
function calert(a) {
    var b = '';
    switch (a) {
        case 'e' {
            b='test'
        }
    alert(b);
}
```

There would be more items in the `switch` statement before the `alert()`, but I removed them for brevity. I use the variable `a` in the function so all images can use the same function.

Also, here's the code for the image with the onclick statement.

```
<img src="https://www.ccohs.ca/images/whmis2015/for_download/biohazardous.png" alt="biohazard" style="width:150px" onclick="calert('e')">
```

Comment: what is the problem?

Comment: Your syntax for `switch` is wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your script has some minor syntax errors which are the cause of your problem. See the comments in the snippet below for details - hope this helps!

```js
function calert(a) {
  var b = '';
  switch (a) { // Add "(a) {" here
    case 'e':  // Add ":" here
      { 
        b = 'test';
      }
  } // Add "}" here
  alert(b);
}
```

```html
<img src="https://www.ccohs.ca/images/whmis2015/for_download/biohazardous.png" alt="biohazard" style="width:150px" onclick="calert('e')">
```

Comment: Thanks. I checked the original, and i was missing the colon on the 'case'. the other parts were me messing up when typing it here (I don't know why I didn't just copy/paste it.)

Answer (score 1):

your switch syntax is wrong

```
function calert(a) {
    var b = '';
    switch (a)
    {
        case 'e':
        b='test'
        break;
    }

    alert(b);
}
```